Permission denied errors using docker image glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 for AWS Glue
I'm trying to build a pipeline that is using glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01. A step in the pipeline is running the docker instance as follows:
   docker run \
    --mount=type=bind,source=./test,target=/home/glue_user/workspace/test \
    --mount=type=bind,source=./libs,target=/home/glue_user/workspace/libs \
    -w /home/glue_user/workspace \
    -e DISABLE_SSL=true \
    -e "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/glue_user/workspace/deps" \
    --rm -p 4040:4040 \
    -p 18080:18080 \
    --name glue_unit_tests docker-default-virtual.${{ vars.ARTIFACTORY_HOST }}/amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 \
    -c "mkdir -p deps/ && pip install -r test/requirements.txt -r libs/requirements.txt -t deps/; cd test && pytest || exit 1"

I am getting multiple permission denied errors when trying to create the deps/ directory inside /home/glue_user/workspace and also pip throws out permission denied errors among with pytest trying to write cache files inside the mounted paths
../deps/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:445   /home/glue_user/workspace/deps/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:445: PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path /home/glue_user/workspace/test/.pytest_cache/v/cache/nodeids: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/glue_user/workspace/test/.pytest_cache'
    config.cache.set("cache/nodeids", sorted(self.cached_nodeids))

../deps/_pytest/stepwise.py:56   /home/glue_user/workspace/deps/_pytest/stepwise.py:56: PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path /home/glue_user/workspace/test/.pytest_cache/v/cache/stepwise: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/glue_user/workspace/test/.pytest_cache'
    session.config.cache.set(STEPWISE_CACHE_DIR, [])


The reason for this is that the user within the container, glue_user, doesn't have write access to the test/ folder. The reason for this is that this folder will have the owner and group from the host.
For example, this is what it looks like on the container for me:
drwxr-xr-x 2 glue_user root 4096 Nov 15 11:20 jupyter_workspace
drwxrwxr-x 2      1000 1000 4096 Apr 18 05:01 libs
drwxrwxr-x 2      1000 1000 4096 Apr 18 05:18 test

The libs/ and test/ folders have user:group ownership of 1000:1000 and the active user, glue_user, therefore doesn't have write access.
But you can set a different cache directory.
In the test/ folder on the host create a pytest.ini file with the following content:
[pytest]
cache_dir = /tmp/pytest-cache/

Your project should then have structure like this:
├── libs
│   └── requirements.txt
└── test
    ├── pytest.ini
    └── requirements.txt

Now when pytest runs on a container it will use a folder, /tmp/pytest-cache/, where it does have write permissions.

Thanks for the answer. Here's an update: There is no problem running this on a couple of laptops. No errors, everything works fine, but on a few other laptops it's throwing out perm denied errors among as our CI

Okay, so let's figure this out.
Did you try setting the pytest.ini file specifying a cache directory under /tmp? If you didn't then please try this first.
If that still doesn't do the trick then let's focus our attention on the problem laptops. For these can you please post a listing of the /home/glue_user/workspace on a running container (like I did in my answer) so that we can see the UID and GID of the mounted folders.
